# Combining two dataframes (one should have a downscaled date, and other has a daily date)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. df1 has a daily time frame (with hours, minutes and seconds) and the other has a monthly time frame as shown below:

df1:

```
Index                    Value
2016-01-01 00:00:00     99
2016-01-02 00:00:00     105
2016-01-03 00:00:00      68
```

df2 (which needs downscaling to daily):

```
Index         Date            Value1           .............................Value 10
 0              31/01/2016        15                 ............................ 98                     
 1              28/02/2016        25                 ............................ 92
 2              31/03/2016        58                 ............................ 68
```

I want to have an output like this:

```
Index            Date       Value   Value1     ..........................Value 10
     0  2016-01-01 00:00:00    99   15         ......................... 98   
     1  2016-01-02 00:00:00    105  15         ......................... 98
     2  2016-01-03 00:00:00    68   15         ......................... 98
```

etc (for february and march and so on)

Data for replication:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Index': ['2016-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-01-02 00:00:00', '2016-01-03 00:00:00'],
                    'Value': [99, 105, 68]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [0, 1, 2],
                    'Date': ['31/01/2016', '28/02/2016', '31/03/2016'],
                    'Value1': [15, 25, 58],
                    'Value10': [98, 92, 68]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dummy "Month" (using `pd.to_datetime` and convert it to `'datetime64[M]'` objects) column for each DataFrame and `merge` (with `how` parameter set to `'outer'` because we don't want to lose any data) them on it. Finally, remove unwanted columns.

```
df2['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']).astype('datetime64[M]')
df1['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Index']).astype('datetime64[M]')

out = (df1.merge(df2, on='Month', how='outer')
       .drop(['Month', 'Date', 'Index_y'], axis=1)
       .rename(columns={'Index_x':'Date'}))
```

Output:

```
                  Date  Value  Value1  Value10
0  2016-01-01 00:00:00   99.0      15       98
1  2016-01-02 00:00:00  105.0      15       98
2  2016-01-03 00:00:00   68.0      15       98
3                  NaN    NaN      25       92
4                  NaN    NaN      58       68
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! but i removed 'Index_y' and replaced 'Index_x' as 'Index' only as it gives me error. I also exchanged df1 and df2 positions in your code 'coz it doesn't give me what I needed. But basically your idea gave me the answer :)